# Result of call to 'rotationEffect(_:anchor:)' is unused

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The idea is simple, I have a button once clicked a I will rotate `Text(titleContent)`.

[image: Click here to see the view]

Inside the view:

```
                ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text(titleContent)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .font(Font.custom("Benguiat Bold", size: 35))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.updateText()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Enter upside down")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding()
                            .border(Color.green, width: 3)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .padding()
                    })
                }
            }
        )
func updateText() {
    Text(titleContent)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .font(Font.custom("Benguiat Bold", size: 35))
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
}
```

Inside the function `updateText()` I get the following warning:

> Result of call to 'rotationEffect(_:anchor:)' is unused

Comment: I guess that "Button(action: {...})" is for some function not for returning a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to return a a new `View` from inside a function that you call as a `Button` action, you need to modify a `@State` property that controls the rotation angle when the user taps the button.

```
struct RotatingView: View {
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0
    let titleContent: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(titleContent)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .font(Font.custom("Benguiat Bold", size: 35))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))

                Button(action: {
                    rotationAngle += 180
                }, label: {
                    Text("Enter upside down")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding()
                        .border(Color.green, width: 3)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```